# Why is there a need to have H₂(g) gas even at the cathode of SHE (standard Hydrogen electrode) / Galvanic cell?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, nernst-equation

In almost all resources I have come across, I have noticed that there is an initial amount of $\ce{H2(g)}$ maintained at 1 bar, kept at the cathode of the standard hydrogen electrode, But what is the need to have this ? If the amount is 0, we get the log term of Nernst equation to be undefined. Wouldn't the reaction still occur as the reactant is still there?

[image: As shown in this image, the H2(g) is sent to the cathode container. shouldn't it be released as a net whole ?]

As shown in this image, the $\ce{H2(g)}$ is sent to the cathode container. shouldn't it be released as a net whole?

I assume that the answer for the above would also answer why metal electrodes are used though they have no role in the reaction. (Eg: Cu and Zn solid metals are used as electrodes in the Daniell cell)

Comment: What do you mean by "cathode of SHE"? It makes impression a part of SHE is not a cathode. SHE is the cathode alongside the zinc anode. 1 atm H2 in SHE is the part of SHE definition. It plays no role elsewhere. Without it, it would be just HE at the best, or not even HE at all. // Why do you think metal electrodes play no role? Where do you think the voltage 0.76 V comes from?

Comment: Ok, please clarify this..In case we had no supply of H2 at cathode initially when we start, would the reaction still take place ? similarly in Daniel cell if we had a platinum electrode instead of Cu electrode at cathode with Cu2+ ions in cathode container, would the reaction still take place /cell Function as it usually does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answer suggests, the [definition of the SHE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_hydrogen_electrode) requires operation with hydrogen gas at 1 bar pressure. In conformance with the [Nernst equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nernst_equation), if the gas is not present at the electrode at that pressure, the cell potential will not have its *standard* value.

A more general form of the half-cell potential (at 298.15 K) of the hydrogen gas electrode
$$\ce{Pt,H2}(p_{\ce{H2}})|\ce{H+}(a_\ce{H+})$$
is
$$E=E^\circ -\pu{0.0591 V} \times (\frac12 \log\left(\frac{p_{\ce{H2}}}{p^\circ} \right)+\mathrm{p}H)$$
Here $p^\circ = \pu{1 bar}$ is defined as the standard pressure. The key word, in case it's not emphasized sufficiently, is standard. When $p_{\ce{H2}}=p^\circ$ and $\mathrm{p} H = 0$ (when $a_\ce{H+}=1$) the potential is $E=E^\circ_\mathrm{SHE}$. This potential is then defined as equal to zero, the *standard* value of the SHE ($E^\circ_\mathrm{SHE}=0$). It is important that the half-cell satisfy this condition when intended as a SHE since providing a specific half-cell voltage is central to its function as a reference electrode.

You don't have to operate a hydrogen electrode as an SHE. You can even pair up two hydrogen electrodes operating at different gas pressures and hydrogen ion activities in one cell, for instance:

$$\mathrm{SHE}||\ce{Pt,H2}(p))|\ce{H+}(a_\ce{H+})$$

where (in this example) one electrode is an SHE (by convention the left half-cell is the anode, therefore it is implied that the SHE is operated with hydrogen gas oxidized). The potential of the galvanic cell in this case is
$$\begin{align}E=&E_\mathrm{cathode}-E_\mathrm{anode}\\=&E^\circ-\pu{0.0591 V} \times (\frac12 \log\left(\frac{p_{\ce{H2}}}{p^\circ} \right)+\mathrm{p}H)-E^\circ\\=&-\pu{0.0591 V} \times (\frac12 \log\left(\frac{p_{\ce{H2}}}{p^\circ} \right)+\mathrm{p}H) \end{align}$$
The cell will operate as written (with the SHE operating as anode) when $E>0$. If we assume the hydrogen ion activity is the same in both half-cells (pH=0)  then this requires that the gas pressure in the cathode $p_{\ce{H2}}<p^\circ$ (the hydrogen gas pressure in the cathode should be less than in the anode).

Note that as written above the cathodic half-cell does not require hydrogen gas since it is a product of the reaction. However if you want the SHE to function as the cathode (swap electrodes) then
$$E=\pu{0.0591 V} \times (\frac12 \log\left(\frac{p_{\ce{H2}}}{p^\circ} \right)+\mathrm{p}H) $$
The SHE will serve as cathode if $p_{\ce{H2}}>p^\circ$ and gas *must* be present for anodic operation of the regular HE.

*Reference*

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_hydrogen_electrode) Skoog, West, and Holler. Fundamentals of Analytical Chemistry, 7th ed., Saunders College Publishing, 1996.

Answer (score 1):

Note that SHE is intended to operate at practically currentless mode, safe the negligible input current of the voltmeter. So the reactions

$\ce{Zn(s) -> Zn^2+(aq) + 2 e-}$ on the zinc anode
$\ce{2 H+(aq) + 2 e- -> H2(aq,g)}$ in SHE

do occur, but with negligible amounts of involved substances. Therefore, if you do not have the $\pu{1 atm}$ hydrogen source for the SHE, you do not have SHE.

Considering the Daniell cell, where copper electrode is replaced by platinum one, the original expected half reactions still occur:

$$\ce{Zn(s) -> Zn^2+(aq) + 2 e-}$$
$$\ce{Cu^2+(aq) + 2 e-  -> Cu(s)}$$

with platinum getting covered by copper, effectively becoming the copper electrode with platinum core.

$\ce{H2}$ is not necessary for the reaction, but $\pu{1 atm}$ $\ce{H2}$ is necessary for SHE technical specification. As the potential of (general = non standard) hydrogen electrode depends on both pH and the partial hydrogen pressure, as Buck Thorn has written in his answer.

Comment: Thank you, got it! But a small query, so are we setting the path for the reaction to happen in a particular way by having that negligible amount of H₂. Is there any particular concept which governs this ?

Comment: I do not get what you exactly mean. Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: "Therefore, if you do not have the 1 atm
 hydrogen source for the SHE, you do not have SHE."


Iam basically asking as to why that minimum amount of H2 is necessary for the reaction. And any associated factor which necessitates this condition.

Comment: Addressed in latest answer updates.

Comment: Another comment the drawing implies equal transference for the various ions, that is rarely the case. also NaCl is a poor choice for a salt bridge because of the different ion mobilities.